# MySql - specifying table columns to use after join

Tags: mysql, join

I've got this simple join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 S
JOIN table2 S2
ON S.PARENT_ID = S2.ID
WHERE S.STATUS = 'TEST'
```

after fetching the results and iterating through the rows, how can I specify which table rows to use? For example, I have the same column name STATUS in both tables, but when using the row  `$row['STATUS']` , it fetches the column from table S2 rather than table S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `JOIN` the result set from both tables are in the same rows.  You should not use `SELECT *` in production (for running queries on the command line I think it's fine).  It's better to be explicit about the queries you want to select.

```
SELECT S.STATUS, S2.STATUS FROM table1 S JOIN table2 S2 ON (PARENT_ID = S.ID)
WHERE S.STATUS = 'TEST'
```

If you want to distinguish them you can also alias the column names.

```
SELECT S.STATUS AS t1_status
```

Then in php, `$row['t1_status']` will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the column names explicitly, and use aliases for the duplicate named ones to access them both from your result set:

e.g.

```
    SELECT s.col1, s.col2, s.STATUS AS s_status, s2.STATUS FROM table1 S
    JOIN table2 S2
    ON S.PARENT_ID = S2.ID
    WHERE S.STATUS = 'TEST'

    print $row['s_status'];    // => data from table S
    print $row['STATUS'];      // => data from table S2
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the columns explicitly in the select instead of using `select *`.